# File locations as URI,can not find file

Tags: java

I have to do simple file operations code based,including copy/delete operations.The problem is if i declare the file location as a path

`File remotefile = new File("//mypc/myfolder/myjar.JAR");`

Windows finds the file in the network and does the operations.How ever Linux machines can not find the file.If i were to use:

`File remotefile = new File("file://mypc/myfolder/myjar.JAR");`

Both platforms find the file.Now i have a method to copy the files which is:

```
public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if(!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    finally {
        if(source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if(destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }
}
```

If I were to send the file URI to this method, both platforms can not find the file. But if I send it as a path, windows machines work properly but linux machines can not find the file.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Use [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) lib.

Comment: What about using Samba on linux machines, since you're probably trying to access a Windows-based network, right ?

Comment: Well, I already use samba,you meant mounting the network path to samba or something?

Comment: What do you mean by “Both platforms find the file”? What method exactly is it which succeeded? As the constructor of the `File` class isn't intended for URI arguments, some method processing it correctly appears to be more likely a coincidence than intended behaviour.

Comment: Well, i simply did a "file.hashcode" check and got no errors,it finds the file and does a hash code check i assume?

Comment: Tried samba jcifs,and still all i got is "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password." no matter what i type. :|